# Taking adress of temporary error while using overloaded operator

Tags: c++, overloading, temporary

I have a string class in my c++ project. I have to use double linked list and make my own string class. In my string class I have to overload `<`, `>` and `==` operators. Actually I did this. But in my other class I have a listing function which compares my string classes. In this comparison I had "taking address of temporary" error.

Here is my string class:

```
#include "String.h"

String::String(int coming)
{
   x=coming;
}

int  String::getX()
{
    return x;
}

String String::operator==(String *taken)
{
    return String (x==taken->x);
}
```

and here is my listing method:

```
void myclass::list(String *taken)
{
    otherclass *temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(&temp->get_string()==taken)//where i get error message.
            cout<<temp<<endl;
        temp=temp->get_nextnode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `temp->get_string() == *taken`, [correction] or `temp->get_string() == taken`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you precisely the problem: you cannot take the address of a temporary object.  `temp->get_string()` is a temporary object<sup>1</sup>, and you are trying to take its address.

I'm not really sure what your aim is here, so I can't suggest a fix.  But I would strongly suggest that defining `String::operator==` to take a pointer as the right-hand side will lead to confusion.  And having it return another `String` makes little sense either; normally one would expect `==` to evaluate to a boolean value.

---

<sub>1. Well, presumably.  You haven't shown the declaration of `get_string()`.</sub>

Comment: 'String myclass::get_String()
{
    return mystring;
}'

its my get_string declaration. i think there is big problem in my design.

Comment: @namcojoulder: Yes, I agree.  I think you need to assess each of your functions in turn, and consider what type it should be returning, what types it should be taking as arguments, and why you would ever need pointers here.

Comment: My aim was compare two Strings with an overloaded operator.

Comment: @namcojoulder: Well that should probably look something like `bool String::operator==(const String &taken)`.

Comment: I did it like this and worked. I was going to say that. You commented before me :D thanks for your answer.